# Short story about The Last Zoo on Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a long time ago a scifi short story about an official who has to go and close down the last zoo. The zoo was just a few pet animals and I think they had to be exterminated which precipitated the owners suicide. Any idea of title and author?

Comment: Do you know any more details on this you can [edit] in? For example, when you read this? This also doesn’t appear to be SFF-nal, can you edit in any details that are SFf-nal?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I think I found it, and it *is* SFF-nal. (By the way, you might want to spell out that abbreviation when commenting to new users. People not already steeped in the world of sci-fi or fantasy might not know what you mean by "SFF-nal".)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Fair point, shall do in the future.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor thanks!

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142912/looking-for-name-of-sci-fi-short-story-all-non-human-life-on-earth-eliminated-t

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for name of sci-fi short story: all non-human life on earth eliminated to preserve equilibrium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142912/) - while acceptance on the present one is murky, I think [this "thanks" comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197843/short-story-about-the-last-zoo-on-earth#comment543032_197843), addressed to the only answerer, might indicate an acceptance. Dupe-target is accepted in comments as well

Answer (score 17):

### Asimov's ["2430 A.D."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2430_A.D.)?

Wikipedia's plot summary says (emphasis mine):

> Earth has established a totally balanced and ecologically stable underground society (similar to that portrayed in Asimov's novel The Caves of Steel). But **one man, Cranwitz, regarded as a deviant and eccentric because he keeps a few animals as pets, refuses to get rid of these animals, the last non-human inhabitants of the planet.**
>
> **He is finally persuaded by his sector representatives to exterminate his pets, but also commits suicide.** This leaves Earth in 'perfection', with its fifteen trillion inhabitants, twenty billion tons of human brain and the 'exquisite nothingness of uniformity'.

I found it via [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/6l548p/tomtshort_story_scifi_story_concerning_the_last/) from someone seeking the same story, which showed up as one of my Google search results (buried under a lot of links to Sara Zaske's short story ["The Last Zoo"](https://sarazaske.com/2013/06/11/new-free-short-story-the-last-zoo/)) when I searched for `short story "last zoo"`.